# Android studio problema RuntimeException

Tags: android, ioexception, runtimeexception

I have problems with Android Studio.
When Android Studio starts, it shows this in Event Log:

RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: El archivo o directorio está dañado o es ilegible: java.io.IOException: El archivo o directorio está dañado o es ilegible

and if I open the MainActivity, the same message is shown repeatedly.

I try uninstalling it and reinstalling, but it doesn´t help.

I hope you can help me

Comment: try to install it in other drive

Comment: If I do it, Android studios works perfectly
But I need to solve it in my computer.
Android was working until I try to use PanoramaGL library.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: open you cmd (command prompt) and enter this command: 
       chkdsk /f c:       Note make sure to replace c: with the drive which is giving you problem like if you have trouble installing in d: you should use   chkdsk /f d: